# What specific use cases would you use id selectors instead of class selectors?

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors

I also found this post, [Why should I not use style IDs using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721166/why-should-i-not-use-style-ids-using-css) saying

> Styling IDs goes against DRY principles and is something that should
>   be avoided, if it makes sense. There are situations where you need to
>   style a single object and you know it will never be shared with
>   anything else on the page so I think saying never style IDs is
>   disingenuous, as long as you're aware of the maintainability risk and
>   it's acceptable do what you need to do to get the job done.

Comment: I updated the question and voted for reopen. Feel free to do the same if my edit can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I use more or less all the time is [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)/[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

They give you a whole lot more than `getElementById` can, though can do the same as well like this, using CSS selectors

```
var el = document.querySelector('#foo');
```

Btw, `id` an element <strike>is not bad practice, though sometimes it</strike> is not as practical as using classes, mainly as they always need to be unique, which on the other hand is their strength, find one using `getElementById` is fast.

Comment: This is sort of what I was looking for.  Thanks man.  However, I was thinking more on the lines of 'pure' javascript and not jquery.

Comment: @IsaacPak `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` _is_ pure javascript

Comment: LOL.  the query part of the function name must have thrown me for a loop.  This is the right answer!

Comment: @IsaacPak Probably :) .. updated my answer with a code sample, to make it more clear